# Casting between contract classes in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I wonder how do you cast between classes in solidity.

For example, if I have these classes:

```
contract Token {
    function getFive() public returns (uint) {
        return 5;
    }
}

contract MyToken is Token {
    function getSix() public returns (uint) {
        return 6;
    }
}
```

And I have this variable in other contract:

```
contract TokenSale {
    Token token;

    function TokenSale(address tokenAddress) {
        token = Token(tokenAddress);
    }
}

contract MyTokenSale is TokenSale {
    function MyTokenSale(address tokenAddress) TokenSale(tokenAddress) {
        // Here I want to call to MyToken's getSix funciton
    }
}
```

How can I downcast the `token` variable in `MyTokenSale` to call `getSix` function, assuming I can't change `TokenSale`'s code?

As an OOP language, I'm sure that Solidity allows you to do it somehow, but for some reason I couldn't find it in the docs.

Thanks!

Comment: In `TokenSale`, why don't you simply declare a state variable of type `MyToken` instead of `Token`? Seems like what you want to achieve, since `MyToken is Token` anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the syntax you would use:

```
MyToken myToken = MyToken(address(token));
```

You have to do it like this because Solidity isn't actually an OOP language, it just has some features that make it feel kinda like it is.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
Token token = Token(address)
```

then, to call a function from the other contract you would write

```
return token.getSix()
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't working. Solidity probably does not support polymorphism.